# How to package Salesforce data (not metadata)

Tags: managed-package, data-loader, custom-metadata, isv

This question is NOT about Custom Metadata Types where records can be indeed be put into Packages. It's about packaging real data. Records of Custom or Standard objects.

Just assume you want to have sample data of your objects or allow people to create new records from existing ones using a Templating feature.

The smartest solution I found so far was using Static Resources (which can be packaged) that store serialized record bundles as JSON. The best way to create and convert back such bundles is [Andy Fawcett's famous SObjectDataLoader](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-sobjectdataloader)

Comment: I've used JSON in static resources. But bear in mind that "A single static resource can be up to 5 MB in size, and an organization can have up to 250 MB of static resources, total.". Given the latter point, including a large proportion of the 250 MB in your package would probably not be a good idea.

Comment: It might sound like a bizarre suggestion, but I've packaged json data in Visualforce pages before now, and used Page.getContent to get the contents....obviously need to be wary of limits etc as usual but worked well (apart from the weird looks from colleagues).